# Reading Chars one by one from string and add them to TMemo

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Adding Characters one by one to TMemo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5688215/adding-characters-one-by-one-to-tmemo)

Hello, 
I have an array of strings. I want to read the chars of the strings one by one in a loop then display them into a Memo (one by one). Can any one tell me how to do it? Thanks

Comment: That is a very broad question with many parts and many possible answers. Can you tell us what it is specifically that you are having a problem doing? And perhaps more importantly, what you have got/tried so far? (show us your code)

Comment: @Ken: yeah, same poster, same start to the question. But that one focussed more on the timer part ... THough you are right, ANdreas' answer addresses both.

Comment: @Marjan, Andreas' code shows accessing the string letter by letter, and adding them to the memo was addressed in my answer to Sue's other post about adding a paragraph to a TMemo as well as by Andreas in his answer. This is a duplicate despite that minor difference. Sue needs to pay attention to what the answers are showing her instead of just copy-pasting the code, or she's not going to learn anything.

Comment: @Ken, just spotted that (in time to edit my comment no less :-)

Comment: @Marjan, no problem. I added to mine while you were adding your last. :)

Answer (score -1):

Use two nested loops. The first iterates over the array of strings. The second iterates over the characters in each string.

```
procedure DisplayCharsOneByOne(const arr: array of string; Memo: TMemo);
var
  s: string;
  c: Char;
begin
  for s in arr do
    for c in s do
      Memo.Lines.Add(c);
end;
```

Comment: When did we start answering duplicate questions instead of closing them?

Comment: I don't think I answered a duplicate, @Ken. What I posted here doesn't even come close to answering the other question. Similarly, the answers there are far more complicated that necessary to answer this question. They're bogged down by things like timers, threads, and paragraphs, none of which are relevant to this question. If answers to *X* don't answer *Y*, and answers to *Y* don't answer *X*, then *X* and *Y* are not duplicates.

Comment: You might be reading between the lines here. The OP didn't say explicitly that she want one character per line in the memo. To me it sounds more like she want to preserve the lines in the string array, and just animate the insertion of the characters, ony by one, that is, the old 'typewriter effect'. And this has been answered. If, on the other hand, the typewriter effect isn't required, and the OP merely wants to load the string array into the memo, then it is *exceedingly* inefficient to do this a single character at a time (and repaint the control once a character)!

Comment: Regardless of other complexities, Andreas' previous answer clearly showed reading a single character at a time from a string (a TStringList.String, to be specific), and adding that single character to a TMemo. Sue needs to learn to read the code she receives in answers and not just paste it in; answering clear duplicates does nothing to assist in that other than providing more code to copy and paste.