# Changing the end of line to a space delphi?

Tags: delphi

I want to print out text onto a RichEdit and make it seem as if it is being typed onto the RichEdit. I have this code:

```pascal
const
  intro = 'Hello world';

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  i : integer;
begin
  for i := 1 to length(intro) do
  begin
    redout.Lines.Add(intro[i]);
    sleep(100);
    form1.Refresh;
  end;
end;

end.
```

But this prints the text onto the rich edit like this

```
H (new line)
e (new line)
l (new line)
l (new line)
o (new line)
...
```

I want to print it like the following, but as if it is being typed one char at a time:

```
Hello world
```

Comment: "Lines.Add" adds a line, which includes a line feed. You can examine the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5688215/adding-characters-one-by-one-to-tmemo).

Answer (score 2):

Every time you call `Lines.Add()`, a hard line break is inserted after the string being added.  To do what you want, you would need to instead move the current caret position to the end of the RichEdit and then insert the string at the new caret position without a line break, eg:

```pascal
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  i : integer;
begin
  for i := 1 to Length(intro) do
  begin
    redout.SelStart := redout.GetTextLen;
    redout.SelLength := 0;
    redout.SelText := intro[i];
    Sleep(100);
    Update;
  end;
end;
```

Which can then be tweaked further to avoid some additional overhead:

```pascal
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  i : integer;
  mask: Integer;
  rng: TCharRange;
  txt: string;
begin
  SetLength(txt, 1);
  mask := SendMessage(redout.Handle, EM_SETEVENTMASK, 0, 0);
  try
    for i := 1 to Length(intro) do
    begin
      rng.cpMin := redout.GetTextLen;
      rng.cpMax := rng.cpMin;
      SendMessage(redout.Handle, EM_EXSETSEL, 0, LPARAM(@rng));
      txt[1] := intro[i];
      SendMessage(redout.Handle, EM_REPLACESEL, TRUE, LPARAM(PChar(txt)));
      SendMessage(redout.Handle, EM_SCROLLCARET, 0, 0);
      Sleep(100);
      Update;
    end;
  finally
    SendMessage(redout.Handle, EM_SETEVENTMASK, 0, mask);
  end;
end;
```